# NCCL operation ncclGroupEnd() failed: unhandled system error

Tags: tensorflow, jax

I am able to run this file [vit_jax.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-research/vision_transformer/blob/master/vit_jax.ipynb#scrollTo=zKn4IfUWHWPk&line=1&uniqifier=1) on colab  and perform training and run my experiments but when I try to replicate it on my cluster, I am getting an error during training given below.
However, the forward pass to calculate accuracy works fine on my cluster.

I have 4 GTX 1080 with CUDA10.1 version on my cluster and using tensorflow==2.4.0 and jax[cuda101]==0.2.18. I am running this as jupyter notebook from inside a docker container.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnfilteredStackTrace                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-176d6124ae02> in <module>()
     11   opt_repl, loss_repl, update_rng_repl = update_fn_repl(
---> 12       opt_repl, flax.jax_utils.replicate(step), batch, update_rng_repl)
     13   losses.append(loss_repl[0])

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jax/_src/traceback_util.py in reraise_with_filtered_traceback(*args, **kwargs)
    182     try:
--> 183       return fun(*args, **kwargs)
    184     except Exception as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jax/_src/api.py in f_pmapped(*args, **kwargs)
   1638         name=flat_fun.__name__, donated_invars=tuple(donated_invars),
-> 1639         global_arg_shapes=tuple(global_arg_shapes_flat))
   1640     return tree_unflatten(out_tree(), out)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jax/core.py in bind(self, fun, *args, **params)
   1620     assert len(params['in_axes']) == len(args)
-> 1621     return call_bind(self, fun, *args, **params)
   1622 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jax/core.py in call_bind(primitive, fun, *args, **params)
   1551   tracers = map(top_trace.full_raise, args)
-> 1552   outs = primitive.process(top_trace, fun, tracers, params)
   1553   return map(full_lower, apply_todos(env_trace_todo(), outs))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jax/core.py in process(self, trace, fun, tracers, params)
   1623   def process(self, trace, fun, tracers, params):
-> 1624     return trace.process_map(self, fun, tracers, params)
   1625 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jax/core.py in process_call(self, primitive, f, tracers, params)
    606   def process_call(self, primitive, f, tracers, params):
--> 607     return primitive.impl(f, *tracers, **params)
    608   process_map = process_call

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jax/interpreters/pxla.py in xla_pmap_impl(fun, backend, axis_name, axis_size, global_axis_size, devices, name, in_axes, out_axes_thunk, donated_invars, global_arg_shapes, *args)
    636                           ("fingerprint", fingerprint))
--> 637   return compiled_fun(*args)
    638 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jax/interpreters/pxla.py in execute_replicated(compiled, backend, in_handler, out_handler, *args)
   1159   input_bufs = in_handler(args)
-> 1160   out_bufs = compiled.execute_sharded_on_local_devices(input_bufs)
   1161   if xla.needs_check_special():

UnfilteredStackTrace: RuntimeError: Internal: external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/nccl_utils.cc:203: NCCL operation ncclGroupEnd() failed: unhandled system error: while running replica 0 and partition 0 of a replicated computation (other replicas may have failed as well).

The stack trace below excludes JAX-internal frames.
The preceding is the original exception that occurred, unmodified.

--------------------

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-176d6124ae02> in <module>()
     10 
     11   opt_repl, loss_repl, update_rng_repl = update_fn_repl(
---> 12       opt_repl, flax.jax_utils.replicate(step), batch, update_rng_repl)
     13   losses.append(loss_repl[0])
     14   lrs.append(lr_fn(step))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jax/interpreters/pxla.py in execute_replicated(compiled, backend, in_handler, out_handler, *args)
   1158 def execute_replicated(compiled, backend, in_handler, out_handler, *args):
   1159   input_bufs = in_handler(args)
-> 1160   out_bufs = compiled.execute_sharded_on_local_devices(input_bufs)
   1161   if xla.needs_check_special():
   1162     for bufs in out_bufs:

RuntimeError: Internal: external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/nccl_utils.cc:203: NCCL operation ncclGroupEnd() failed: unhandled system error: while running replica 0 and partition 0 of a replicated computation (other replicas may have failed as well).
```

Please let me know if anyone has faced this issue before? Or any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know for sure without more information, but this error can be caused by running out of GPU memory. Depending on your local settings, you may be able to remedy it by upping the proportion of the GPU memory reserved by XLA, e.g. by setting the `XLA_PYTHON_CLIENT_MEM_FRACTION` system variable to `0.9` or something similarly high.

Alternatively, you could try running your code on a smaller problem that fits into memory on your local hardware.

Comment: I am able to run the same code on a single GPU by decreasing the batch size (same as you mentioned above) but it's not working with multiple-GPUs even with small data.